# React router V6 and redirect/rewrite declarative routes

Tags: react-router, url-routing, declarative

I'm using `createBrowserRouter` to define routing in my app. I would also like to define some redirect/rewrite routes like:

```
/original => /redirected/location
```

and I'm able to define these quite simply by

```
{
  path: '/original',
  element: <Navigate replace to="/redirected/location" />
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I would like to redirect a route with path parameter:

```
/original/:paramName => /redirected/location/:paramName
```

**How do I handle these in the declarative way to extract and remap the same variable value to the new URL?**

> **Note**: I've created my own component to accomplish this, but I suspect this should be solvable with out of the box functionality without resorting to custom components.

## What I tried: Custom navigate component

```js
interface Props {
    paramName: string;
    to: (value: string) => string;
}

export const NavigateWithParam: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ paramName, to }) => {
    const paramValue = useParams()[paramName];
    return <Navigate replace to={to(paramValue ?? '')} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You will have to create a custom "Navigate" component that can read the current path params, and pass, i.e. forward, those to the new path via the [`generatPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/generate-path) utility function. Note that the params that should be forwarded should maintain the same path param name in the new path.

```
import { Navigate, NavigateProps, generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

export const NavigateWithParams = ({ to, ...props }: NavigateProps) => {
  const params = useParams();
  return <Navigate {...props} to={generatePath(to, params)} />;
};
```

```
{
  path: "/original/:paramName",
  element: <NavigateWithParams replace to="/redirected/location/:paramName" />
}
```

Comment: I wonder why isn't this supported on the `Navigate` component out of the box? Seems very rudimentary...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Likely the difference between a path string that is used for matching, e.g. `path` prop of `Route` and can be dynamic to match multiple paths, and a target path string, e.g. the `to` prop, a "link" would use, which needs to target a specific path value.